# Block pages opened from JavaScript

Tags: firefox, javascript, blocking, popups

Some websites open pages in a new browser window automatically, thanks to JavaScript. For example, when clicking at a play button, the video starts and another page gets opened in a new window. AFAIK, these are different from classical pop-ups, so the default pop-up blocker doesn’t prevent this.

With the `about:config` settings [`browser.link.open_newwindow`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow) (`3`) and [`browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction) (`0`), these annoying windows get opened in tabs instead.

However, I’d like to block them, just like normal pop-ups get blocked. Firefox should notify me about blocked attempts to open a new page, and allow me to select the ones that should be displayed anyway.

How could I achieve this?

(I don’t want to use a general ad-blocker, and blocking JavaScript is no solution as the scripts of the sites in question need to be white-listed in my NoScript.)

Comment: If it's a smart website, then the new window might *not* be opened by JavaScript (that's why browsers allow it to open; they have no way of telling you didn't want to open the window), but instead the video is started using JavaScript just before the new page is opened...

Comment: Tried checking in NoScript's settings? There's a ton of different options in there, may need a web search to figure out the right one though